# How can DFT of a two dimensional array be found using program for one dimensional DFT in C?

Tags: c, fourier-analysis

I have the program `four1.c` from Numerical Recipes in C to calculate the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of a one dimensional array. I want to calculate the DFT of a two dimensional array using `four1.c`, how can I do it?

Comment: Why not just use a 2-dimensional FFT library?

Comment: I think @BillBarth is right, why not use something like FFTW?

Comment: Yeah, I'd just use a 2-D FFT library. Hypothetically, one might object to using a GPL'd library. SciPy uses FFTPACK instead of FFTW due to licensing issues, and FFTPACK only implements 1-D transforms, so SciPy implements $n$-D FFTs by composing 1-D FFTs from FFTPACK. (For an in-house tool not intended for distribution, it's all moot anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

You just take the DFT across each row and then across each column, or columns then rows, it doesn't matter.